# cisco switch iOS running into problem

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, cisco-2960

I updated Cisco 2960x iOS, but when it started to operate I encountered this error.

"Mar 25 12:02:19.878: %ILET-1-AUTHENTICATION_FAIL: This Switch may not have been manufactured by Cisco or with Cisco's authorization.  This product may contain software that was copied in violation of Cisco's license terms.  If your use of this product is the cause of a support issue, Cisco may deny operation of the product, support under your warranty or under a Cisco technical support program such as Smartnet.  Please contact Cisco's Technical Assistance Center for more information."

I know that there is no need for a software license for Cisco 2960x.
I don't know what I should do!?!?!

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears that you have a counterfeit switch. How did you acquire the device?

Comment: @RonMaupin - I bought it from a local vendor in Iran.

Comment: You need to get your money back. Also, you need to report it to Cisco TAC, as it explains in the message above. Possessing counterfeit goods is actually a crime.

Comment: Just commenting that the law on counterfeit goods varies considerably from one jurisdiction to another.  In the UK for example, my understanding is that attempting to profit financially from counterfeit goods is a crime, various civil laws have been broken by the seller as regards copyright etc, but a naive buyer hasn't broken any laws by the possession.  Without a doubt unwise and risky in a number of directions: get your money back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like some other people also had the same issue, for some people, hard resetting the device worked fine. You can find the thread [here](https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/ilet-1-authentication-fail-on-2960x-after-ios-update/td-p/3682974)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

it is NOT a counterfeit device. it is a well known issue with the IOS.

Comment: Please consider improving this answer by adding some details on what the known issue is and how one can determine if this is the case here.